# How to make an activity start without clicking notification even when the app is closed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app where users can call each other through an SDK. Everything is working fine. I just need to be able to make calls like fabebook and whatsapp even when the app is closed. It should be able to start a particular activity even when the app is completely closed. I've followed some stackoverflow questions and I tried using the notification receiver but Its not working.

NotificationReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intentNotification = new Intent();
        intentNotification.setAction("com.start.app");
        context.sendBroadcast(intentNotification);
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".Notifications.NotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"></receiver>
```

Comment: service is what you are looking for

Comment: What exactly isn't working about it? In order to fix issues, we need specific explanations of exactly what you are trying to do and what about it isn't working

Comment: @npk Change receiver to service?

Comment: @DaxeshVekariya Be able to start a particular activity even when the app is completely closed with the help of a notification. But the above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you looking for ..
This can be done by creating a broadcast receiver class and send a broadcast when message received and on your broadcast receivers onReceive method call the specific activity you wish to open.
Dont forget to add the reciever in your manifest
Not tested but i think it will work..

Comment: These won't work in latest android (Android 10). [Check this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

Comment: It also works in android 10 but you just need to follow some guidelines of android 10. Please check carefully 

"Exceptions to the restriction"

Comment: @AswinPAshok Due to restrictions, do you suggest just showing the notification if the app is closed?

Comment: @DaxeshVekariya Isn't it possible with ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL as suggested in exceptions?